# Meaning of "steady-as-she-goes financial package"

Tags: meaning, idioms, expressions

I was reading [this article](http://www.guardian.co.uk/uk/2011/mar/22/budget-2011-george-osborne) and I'm not sure about the meaning of this sentence:

> Despite rise in inflation and
>   borrowing, chancellor to court medium
>   earners in **'steady-as-she-goes'
>   financial package**

Could you explain me what the author meant by *"steady-as-she-goes" financial package*?

Could it be something like "a financial package that is congruent with previous economic policies"?

PS: Is this kind of question appropriate for this site?

Comment: Dear Gelu, welcome to English Language & Usage. Your question is perfectly appropriate!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was originally a maritime expression, where *she* refers to a vessel and it is an instruction to maintain the current course.  So the author is saying that with this budget, the chancellor is continuing in the same policy direction.

Comment: I'd upvote but I don't have enough rep yet :). F'x's answer is good too but this one explains not only the idiom but also the sentence from the article.

Answer (score 6):

The original expression refers to a ship (hence *she*), and means to keep on a steady course.
A discussion thread [here](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/54/messages/88.html) says:

> It is an instruction from the captain to the helmsman of a ship, to keep the ship heading steadily on the same course regardless of gusts of wind or cross-currents.